# Ruby on Rails server initiation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

First time using rails. I have everything installed. I tried to make an application work and do the server but it keeps failing. This is what I get. If anyone can help thank you.
Im on a windows 10 operating system.

```
C:\\>cd C:\test_app

C:\test_app>rails s <br>
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x64-mingw32/lib/nokogiri
.rb:29:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x64-mingw32
/lib/nokogiri.rb:29:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x64-mingw32
/lib/nokogiri.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/loofah-2.0.3/lib/loofah.rb:3
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/loofah-2.0.3/lib/loofah.rb:3
:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.2/l
ib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.2/l
ib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_
view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:3:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_
view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_
view/helpers/text_helper.rb:32:in `<module:TextHelper>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_
view/helpers/text_helper.rb:29:in `<module:Helpers>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_
view/helpers/text_helper.rb:6:in `<module:ActionView>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_
view/helpers/text_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_
view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:18:in `<module:FormTagHelper>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_
view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:14:in `<module:Helpers>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_
view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:8:in `<module:ActionView>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_
view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_
view/helpers/form_helper.rb:4:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_
view/helpers/form_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_
view/helpers.rb:50:in `<module:Helpers>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_
view/helpers.rb:4:in `<module:ActionView>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_
view/helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sp
rockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:7:in `<module:LegacyAssetTagHelper>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sp
rockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:6:in `<module:Rails>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sp
rockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:4:in `<module:Sprockets>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sp
rockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sp
rockets/rails/helper.rb:45:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sp
rockets/rails/helper.rb:45:in `<module:Helper>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sp
rockets/rails/helper.rb:7:in `<module:Rails>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sp
rockets/rails/helper.rb:6:in `<module:Sprockets>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sp
rockets/rails/helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sp
rockets/railtie.rb:6:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sp
rockets/railtie.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.4/lib/sass/ra
ils/railtie.rb:3:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.4/lib/sass/ra
ils/railtie.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.4/lib/sass/ra
ils.rb:11:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.4/lib/sass/ra
ils.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.4/lib/sass-ra
ils.rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.4/lib/sass-ra
ils.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.r
b:134:in `require'
        from C:/test_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/com
mands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please refer this https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1256

Answer (score -2):

First of all, have you write `bundle install` ?

Secondly, are you sure to have 'gem'?

In my opinion, you should install ubuntu (really simple to use, see : https://www.codecademy.com/ command line tutorial) and code on it. To install ubuntu you can download something like virtualbox (free) to create a virtual machine.

Why I tell you this? Because code on windows is really hard. You will have a lot of problems.

I have try to install a new project but my rails automatically execute `bundle install`, sorry :s

Comment: I fixed it. Theres a problem with Nokogiri and its versions, simply had to uninstall and then do 'gem install nokogiri --pre'